# Taking the average of three rows in a dataframe and finding the average while ignoring missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, average

I'm completely new to R so forgive me for my missing knowledge.

I need to take 3 numeric rows in a data frame and create a new row that contains the average of the three rows. The data set has a lot of missing values. I have tried to create a for loop to solve the problem, but I cant get it to work as intended.
There surely is a much easier way to solve it, which I am very interested in knowing as well, but I would also like to know what's wrong with my for loop.

```
count<-0

for (i in nrow(data.frame)) {

if (is.na(data.frame$a[i])==FALSE) {
          count<-count+1 }
    if (is.na(data.frame$b[i])==FALSE) {
            count<-count+1 }
    if (is.na(data.frame$c[i])==FALSE) {
            count<-count+1 }
    if (count==0) {
      next}
    new_vector[i]<-(data.frame$a[i]+data.frame$b[i]+data.frame$c[i])/count
    count<-0
}
```

The logic being that if all one or more of my variables (a,b,c) is missing the count variable would account for this causing the sum of the three variables to be divided by the number of non-missing values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would the `na.rm` argument be of help to you? `mean( your.values, na.rm=TRUE )`

Comment: Your code seems to calculate the mean of 3 columns, while your quetsion says to calculate the mean of 3 rows, which is it you want?

Comment: Whilst there's no data, I suspect that you're looking for `dplyr::mutate()` and `dplyr::across()`, making use of `na.rm=TRUE`, all of which is well documented online. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/

Comment: Note the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag which ask for complete reproducible questions.  The input should be cut down to provide a minimal example and shown using dput along wiith the expected output.